# How do I send a secure cookie over HTTPS on Android Retrofit 2/OkHTTP3?

Tags: android, https, retrofit, csrf

I'm using Retrofit 2. For some reason, my Android app can never succeed calling backend Django API due to CSRF token failure because CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE is set to True. So how do I send the cookies over OkHttp3 and Retrofit 2 as secure (over HTTPS)?